# Assertion Error when trying to integrate Redis into Node.js (TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, callback, redis

someone who's somewhat new to Redis and is somewhat novice at Node here.

I've been trying to integrate the `node-redis` module with a Typescript Node project I've been working on, which I've been testing with `mocha` and `chai`.

I'm trying to write basic Getter/Setter Functions I can integrate with the rest of my project (I'm using Redis to track the state of a Facebook Messenger Bot).

Any time I try to write a new Key-Value pair to the DB with my `setKeyValue` function, the transaction goes through (as verified through the `redis-cli` client), but the values returned for both `setKeyValue` and `getValueFromKey` don't correspond to what they should if the DB transaction was successful.

The code implementation I've written is below (in my `redis_interaction.ts` file):

```js
import * as redis from 'redis';
var client = redis.createClient("6379", "127.0.0.1");

enum RedisResponse {
  OK,
  Fail
}


    // 'Setter' Function for Key Value Pairs within Redis Database
export function setKeyValue(key : string, value : string): RedisResponse {
  client.set(key, value, function(err, reply) {
    if(!err) {
      return RedisResponse.OK;
    }
  });
  return RedisResponse.Fail;
}

// 'Getter' Function for Key Value Pairs within Redis Database
export function getValueFromKey(key : string) : [string, RedisResponse] {
  client.get(key, function(err, reply) {
    if(!err) {
      return[reply, RedisResponse.OK];
    }
  });
  return["", RedisResponse.Fail];
}

// 'Delete' Function for Removing Keys from within Redis Database
export function deleteKeyFromRedis(key : string) : RedisResponse {
  client.del(key, function(err, reply) {
    if(!err) {
      if(reply) {
        return RedisResponse.OK;
      }
    }
  });
  return RedisResponse.Fail;
}
```

I test this code with the following `mocha` tests:

```js
import {expect, assert} from 'chai';
import 'mocha';
import * as RedisInteraction from '../redis_interaction';
import {RedisResponse} from '../redis_types';

describe("Redis IO Works as expected", function() {
  describe("Can GET/SET", function() {
    it('Should be able to SET {Key, Value} Pair', function() {
      var result = RedisInteraction.setKeyValue("key","value");
      expect(result).to.equal(RedisResponse.OK);
    });

    it('Should be able to GET Value from Key', function() {
      const response = RedisInteraction.getValueFromKey("key");
      expect(response).to.equal("value");
    });
  });
  describe("Can DEL", function() {
    before(function() {
      RedisInteraction.setKeyValue("key_to_delete","value");
    });
    it("Should be able to DEL Key from Redis DB", function() {
      expect(RedisInteraction.deleteKeyFromRedis("key_to_delete"))
      .to.equal(RedisResponse.OK);
    });
  });
});
```

However, when I actually run `npm test`, I receive the following errors:

```
> mocha lib/test/



  Redis IO Works as expected
    Can GET/SET
      1) Should be able to SET {Key, Value} Pair
      2) Should be able to GET Value from Key
    Can DEL
      3) Should be able to DEL Key from Redis DB


  0 passing (13ms)
  3 failing

  1) Redis IO Works as expected Can GET/SET Should be able to SET {Key, Value} Pair:

      AssertionError: expected 1 to equal 0
      + expected - actual

      -1
      +0

      at Context.<anonymous> (lib/test/redis_test.js:11:38)

  2) Redis IO Works as expected Can GET/SET Should be able to GET Value from Key:
     AssertionError: expected [ '', 1 ] to equal 'value'
      at Context.<anonymous> (lib/test/redis_test.js:15:40)

  3) Redis IO Works as expected Can DEL Should be able to DEL Key from Redis DB:

      AssertionError: expected 1 to equal 0
      + expected - actual

      -1
      +0

      at Context.<anonymous> (lib/test/redis_test.js:24:21)
```

Am I doing something wrong regarding callbacks? For the life of me, I don't understand why the callbacks I've written aren't working correctly.

Many thanks, apologies for potential verbosity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is how you are currently handling the asynchronous nature of the calls to redis.  Looking at this function...

```
export function setKeyValue(key : string, value : string): RedisResponse {

  client.set(key, value, function(err, reply) {
    if(!err) {
      // Not a return from setKeyValue function
      return RedisResponse.OK;
    }
  });

  // Return value from setKeyValue
  return RedisResponse.Fail;
}
```

You call the client `set` function, and provide a callback.  Execution will continue immediately, and reach the `return RedisResponse.Fail` statement.  The first return statement is actually a return from inside the callback - it is discarded as it is not used anywhere.

To write your `setKeyValue` function to accommodate this asynchronicity, it needs to have a callback argument:

```
export function setKeyValue(key : string, value : string, callback: (err: Error, response: RedisResponse) => void): void {

  client.set(key, value, function(err, reply) {
    // Now we know whether we succeeded

    // If there is an error, invoke the callback with the error
    // and a fail response
    if(err) {
      return callback(err, RedisResponse.Fail);
    }

    // Otherwise invoke it with a null error and an OK response
    callback(null, RedisResponse.OK);
  });
}
```

When you are testing the function you need to wait for the async call to redis to finish, and *then* make your assertion - you can do this by providing a callback in the test:

```
it('Should be able to SET {Key, Value} Pair', function() {
  RedisInteraction.setKeyValue("key", "value", (err, redisResponse) => {
    expect(redisResponse).to.equal(RedisResponse.OK);
  });
});
```

Just as an alternative to using this callback style of coding, it is often nicer to use a Promise-based implementation.  `node-redis` doesn't provide this for you, but it is relatively simple to implement.  I have removed the RedisResponse enum because it really isn't necessary - the resolution/rejection of the promise tells you whether the call succeeded or not. (This is also true for the above implementation)  The above function would become:

```
export function setKeyValue(key : string, value : string): Promise<null> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    client.set(key, value, function(err, reply) {
      if(err) {
        // If there's an error reject the promise providing the error
        return reject(err);
      }
      // Otherwise resolve it
      resolve();
  });
}
```

You can then test it with:

```
it('Should be able to SET {Key, Value} Pair', function() {
  RedisInteraction.setKeyValue("key", "value")
  .then(() => {
     // Your test has passed, no need to do anything
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // Your test failed, do something to let mocha know
    expect(true).to.equal(false);
  });
});
```

Having shown you this, it is worth pointing out that the functions you have shown in your question don't appear to add any functionality over the `node-redis` functions, except for adding the (unnecessary) RedisResponse enum.  Essentially what you are testing is that `node-redis` works as it should, and that is the job of the authors of the library, not yours!